# Polygon highlighting with Mapbox or Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to replicate polygon highlighting on mouseover event in mapbox.js or leaflet.js similar to the example below:

http://projects.nytimes.com/census/2010/explorer?view=raceethnicity&lat=40.6311&lng=-73.994&l=12

How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Leaflet, you simply have to define a function to set the style of the polygon on mouseover event. For example:

```
polygonLayer.on('mouseover', function (this) {
    this.setStyle({
        fillOpacity: 0,
        color: 'black'
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a per-feature hover effect by using events and feature states of Mapbox GL JS.

Follow this [link](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/) for implementation!